# How would I change the opacity of an img using a slider through the use of an eventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my html:

```
<main>
<div id="sliderBox">
    <form>
       <p><label>Saturation: </label><input type="range" id="sliderSaturation" min="1" max="300" value="100" class="sliders"/> <span id="numSaturation">100</span>%</p>
    </form>    
</div>
<figure id="imgManipulated">
    <img src="images/medium/painting1.jpg" > 

</figure>  
</main>
```

I want to use javascript eventListener to take input and change the saturation of the img using the slider

I've grabbed the img and set up the eventListener, but I'm stuck as to what to do from here.

```
const img2Change = document.querySelector("#imgManipulated img");
img2Change.addEventListener('input', function(){


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this?

Also, the `input` event works only on input, not on image.

```js
const sliderOpacity = document.querySelector("#sliderOpacity");
const img = document.querySelector("#imgManipulated");

sliderOpacity.addEventListener('input', function(){
  img.style.opacity = (sliderOpacity.value)/100;
// I divide by 100 because "opacity" takes a value between 0 and 1.
});
```

```html
<main>
<div id="sliderBox">
    <form>
       <label>Opacity: </label><p><input type="range" id="sliderOpacity" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="sliders" /> <span id="numOpacity">100</span>%
    </form>    
</div>
<figure id="imgManipulated">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" > 

</figure>  
</main>
```